# Converting React component to hook

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to convert an old gatsby site to begin using hooks. I have this one feature that is confusing me. I have the code below:

In the index.js file, there is:

```
export default class Home extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    new window.CABLES.Patch({
      patchFile: '/patch/js/Banner_-_FP.json',
      prefixAssetPath:'/patch/',
      glCanvasId:'cables-canvas',
      glCanvasResizeToParent: true,
    });
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="home">

        <div className="section-banner" id="cables-container">
          <div className="canvas">
            <canvas id="cables-canvas"></canvas>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I have the '/patch/js/Banner_-_FP.json' in a component folder already. I am just wondering how to convert this section to use hooks if possible:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    new window.CABLES.Patch({
      patchFile: '/patch/js/Banner_-_FP.json',
      prefixAssetPath:'/patch/',
      glCanvasId:'cables-canvas',
      glCanvasResizeToParent: true,
    });
  }
```

Any input would be great. thanks!

Comment: there is a react function called `useEffect` you can read about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: @kunalpanchal thanks, i do know about the useEffect, I'm not sure how to apply it spefically to the "new window.CABLES.Patch" section

Answer (score 0):

you can use an hook called useEffect and pass the second parameter which is array deps as empty, so when you pass array deps as empty array it will be triggered same as the componentDidMount, you can read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

```
 useEffect(() => {
     new window.CABLES.Patch({
      patchFile: '/patch/js/Banner_-_FP.json',
      prefixAssetPath:'/patch/',
      glCanvasId:'cables-canvas',
      glCanvasResizeToParent: true,
    });
 }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

simply like this:

The [Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) has already used an example for conversion please check it out

```
    componentDidMount() {
        new window.CABLES.Patch({
          patchFile: '/patch/js/Banner_-_FP.json',
          prefixAssetPath:'/patch/',
          glCanvasId:'cables-canvas',
          glCanvasResizeToParent: true,
        });
      }
      
      
    useEffect(() => {
      new window.CABLES.Patch({
          patchFile: '/patch/js/Banner_-_FP.json',
          prefixAssetPath:'/patch/',
          glCanvasId:'cables-canvas',
          glCanvasResizeToParent: true,
        }); 
    },[])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look something like:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const Home = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const applyPatch = () => {
      new window.CABLES.Patch({
        patchFile: '/patch/js/Banner_-_FP.json',
        prefixAssetPath: '/patch/',
        glCanvasId: 'cables-canvas',
        glCanvasResizeToParent: true,
      });
    };

    applyPatch();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="home">

      <div className="section-banner" id="cables-container">
        <div className="canvas">
          <canvas id="cables-canvas"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

I am not sure what exactly this `new window.CABLES.Patch()` is doing and if it is a good idea to attach it to the `window` object at all and execute it in this manner but if it has any dependencies, you should supply them to the second parameter of `useEffect`(the empty `[]`). This will basically also handle the `componentDidUpdate` class hook. Also, if this code should have some clean-up logic(one, which you would execute in a `componentWillUnmount`), you should handle that in the `useEffect` also by returning a cleanup function.